# How to pick a file when writing the name

Tags: python

Ok, so I have .txt files of each of these names below, I want the user to be able to pick a name, then that .txt is opened and printed. Does anyone know how I would do this? the main problem is the
`f = open('name.txt','r')`
where it is normal like this.
I thought it would be something like this
`f = open(name'.txt','r')`
but this gives me an invalid syntax.
I am quite new to all of this, it would be amazing if someone could help me out. This is Python btw :D

```
print("""here is the list of names.
John
Garry
Tom
Jim
Bob
Jerry
Timmy""")
name=input("please type the name you would like: ")
f = open('name.txt','r')
message = f.read()
print(message)
f.close()
```

Answer (score 3):

You just need to create your name file by concatenating `name` and the string `".txt"`, which you can do with the `+` operator:

```
name=input("please type the name you would like: ")
f = open(name + '.txt','r')
message = f.read()
print(message)
f.close()
```

Or, to make it more consise, the following is completely equivalent:

```
name=input("please type the name you would like: ")
with open(name + '.txt', 'r') as f:
    print(f.read())
```

Comment: python is really nice with handling user input, but you may want to wrap the input with str() to be safe! Just suggesting!

Comment: Unless I'm much mistaken, `input` in python is always read as a string by default... you can try it by giving it an `int` or some other numeric, and then testing `type(my_input_variable)`, it should be `str`. However, you're right in saying that you should explicitely cast it to whatever data type you want if it is anything beside `str` that you are after!

Comment: Ah, didn't realize it defaulted to string, thanks for informing me!

Answer (score 0):

In order to open the correct file, you should do whats called a string concatenation:

```
print("""here is the list of names.
John
Garry
Tom
Jim
Bob
Jerry
Timmy""")
name = str(input("please type the name you would like: "))
f = open(name + '.txt','r')
message = f.read()
print(message)
f.close()
```

Can you paste the syntax error perhaps in case i am missing something else?